# Save matplotlib plot when running Python2 application on Linux server with no display

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

Is it possible to use matplotlib plot or a plotting tool similar to this, to save a plot in a python2 application to a file when there is no display on the server I'm working on?

Context:
I am sshing onto a server cluster running New Debian to run a series of large optimisations in Python. I'd really like to be able to save those optimisations as plots (eg. a file such as "opt-100.png") as well as the raw data. I am unable to do so as neither pylab nor matplotlib.pyplot can be imported because there's no display (ie. "RuntimeError: could not open display" is thrown by python when I try and import them).

I realise I am able to save the raw data and then scp that onto my local machine but due to the current configuration of my code that would be a lot of work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend for Matplotlib has to be set to use software rendering instead of hardware rendering. Try this before any matplotlib or pylab imports:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, allows me to import! Will update my code and let you know how I go!!

Comment: I ran into the same issue on RHEL a few months ago. This change made PuTTy logins without X11 port forwarding to an XServer possible for making Matplotlib graphics. If you need interactive graphics via SSH, enable X11 port forwarding and install an XServer, or (my perference) try out MobaXTerm.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense! Unfortunately here I have fairly minimal permissions on the server so I don't think I'd be able to enable port forwarding myself.

Comment: It only needs to be enabled on the client side, the server is inherently set up for it already. Installing Moba for me was easier than messing with X11; it's enabled by default.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :/ on one of the servers the error is as follows: "Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "localhost:10.0"." and on the other (more important one) it has a rather massive error: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1005: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time." followed by "RuntimeError: could not open display"

Comment: Actually, managed to get past that second problem but is still refusing to save the plots :/

Comment: Wow, I got there!! Didn't think it was gonna happen haha. Many thanks for assistance Brian :)